# Creating vectors.dense, and sparse.dense, are they identical?

Tags: python, apache-spark, vector, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to make more sense of these two types, so i am creating these 2 arrays to see if i am doing it right. What i am doing now is creating 2 identical arrays, my goal is:

```
dv = [1.0, 0.0, 3.0]
sv = [1.0, 0.0, 3.0]
```

So i wrote the syntax below,

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()


dv = Vectors.dense(1.0, 0.0, 3.0)
    
sv = Vectors.sparse(3, [(0,2), (1.,3.)])
```

Therefore, my first question is, is my syntax correct for achieving my goal?

my second question is, when i print them,

```
print(dv)
print(sv)
```

they return:

```
[1.0,0.0,3.0]
(3,[0,1],[2.0,3.0])
```

so, how do i show the "real" array of sv? like not in this "Vectors.dense? form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The creation of the sparse vector is slightly incorrect. From the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.linalg.Vectors.sparse): the second and third parameter should be

> two sorted lists containing indices and values

This gives

```python
sv = Vectors.sparse(3, [0,2], [1.,3])
```

To transform the vectors into an arrays the function [vector_to_array](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.functions.vector_to_array) can be used.

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.ml.functions import vector_to_array

spark.createDataFrame([(dv,), (sv,)], ['col1']) \
    .withColumn("as_array", vector_to_array(F.col('col1'))) \
    .show(truncate=False)
```

prints

```
+-------------------+---------------+
|col1               |as_array       |
+-------------------+---------------+
|[1.0,0.0,3.0]      |[1.0, 0.0, 3.0]|
|(3,[0,2],[1.0,3.0])|[1.0, 0.0, 3.0]|
+-------------------+---------------+
```